# When are complicated trig functions used?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I am teaching my son calculus. Sometimes there are very tough integrals that involve functions like "$\sin(2x)\tan(x+1)$." These are sometimes raised to various powers. In any event, the functions have multiple trigonometric functions - could be any of the $6$ trigonometric  functions - multiplied or divided by other trigonometric functions.

My question: what are the practical application of these complicated trigonometric  functions? Where are these functions encountered in real life? I'm not a physicist or advanced mathematician, so I'm interested in learning where these complicated trig functions show up in engineering or advanced science. When would I see something that is modeled by these things, because I never run across them myself?

EDIT: It's not just integrals. I just saw this on twitter. Where would you see this function in the wild?[image]

Comment: I wonder if this question is better suited to our [Math Educators StackExchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) sister site.

Comment: My 2p:  When doing integrals, you need to spot patterns and apply suitable tricks, because (unlike differentiation) there is no algorithm that can reliably solve them. This is non-trivial to teach. So, doing all sorts of integrals is just a way how the student builds their own inexact algorithms in their head, by seeing a lot of different examples. Otherwise, how do you practise any nontrivial activity like that? Do Katas in Karate, seemingly boring exercises in music, or studying old games in chess help the person in a future fight, at a concert, or in a new game of chess? Most likely yes.

Comment: Well at the very least for sines and cosines, their products appear all the time, especially when talking about Fourier series (in particular their “orthogonality” with respect to the $L^2$ inner product), and Fourier series appears all over the place in physics and engineering (electrical for example). Anyway, the main purpose at the elementary level is simply to gain familiarity with the definitions and basic properties of trig functions (pythagorean identity, addition formulae and their consequences like half and double angle and factor formulae etc).

Comment: As said, footballers don't do keepy-uppies in football, but good players can do them with all kinds of variations. It's about developing a level of comfort with the ball.

Comment: Aside from products of sines and cosines, I haven’t “actually” met crazy products of trig functions. Like I said, all these weird integrals/algebraic stuff is merely to gain familiarity, so that in the middle of a big “actual” calculation/application you don’t forget the basics.

Comment: I do understand the need to do practice with them. I was just curious if these kind of function have real-world applicability.

Comment: It would help if you gave us explicit examples, so that we could recognise (or not) their real-life applications and/or educational purpose. My guess is, for example, that $\int\sin(2x)\tan(x+1)\,dx$ has a pure educational purpose - perhaps to spot that the entire integral can be converted (e.g. by a substitution $\tan x=t$) to an integral of a rational function. This is because I find it unlikely to see an angle of $1\text{ rad}$ or $1^\circ$ anywhere - it is a "magic number" as we would say in computer programming. Why not $2.7\text{ rad}$ or $47^\circ$?

Comment: The fact that this is what you're curious about shows that even when you were introduced to calculus for the first time, you did not learn the ultimate lesson that calculus+, unlike algebra or trig, is more about learning how to think than it is about learning algorithms.  I always ask, why must there be a real-world application for anything we learn in math?

Comment: Signals and systems. Products of trig functions show up there. But don't expect every integral to have a "real-world application." That's not a good way to think about mathematics.

Comment: Most people will have no need to evaluate trig integrals, much as few need to deal with PEMDOS, etc. Academics, physicists, control/comms engineers, etc, may encounter them. Trig pops up in unexpected places such as Chebyshev approximation.

Comment: Scattering experiments of high-spin particles in QFT feature an integral over product and linear combinations of powers of sin(\theta/2) and cos(\theta/2)

Comment: Btw, that Twitter click-bait wants you to engage because you feel clever for realising that you can more or less ignore that sixths power when you determine where those maxima are. If I didn’t make a mistake then you have a maximum at $-\pi/4$ with a value of $8$.

Comment: @AndrewChin Calculus is among the most applicable disciplines in math. It is very natural to ask where standard calculus problems are applicable.

Comment: Just got back to this question and saw the question about the maximum value of $(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)^6$. Surely - when does _anything_ to $6$th degree has a maximum? When the thing under the $6$th degree has a maximum of its _absolute value_. So you only need to maximize $|\cos\theta-\sin\theta|$. Now it is the matter of general knowledge to understand that $A\cos\theta+B\sin\theta=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\cos(\theta + \phi)$ for some $\phi$, i.e. adding and subtracting sines/cosines just makes a new sine/cosine-like wave. In this case $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}=\sqrt{2}$ etc. etc.

Comment: In other words, the student is, by the sheer size of exponent $6$, nudged to **not** use brute force and instead try to combine some prior knowledge about powers, sums of trigonometric functions etc.

Comment: @AndrewChin Calculus is all about calculating areas, volumes, calculating flows, etc. Euclidean geometry comes closer to teaching purely how to think. If we were choosing a field of mathematics to teach about thinking, why not first-order logic, set theory, category theory or algebra? Personally, there is so much fascinating mathematics without getting tangled in the particular characteristics of an uncountable field that the only reason to teach calculus so early is the practical ones.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Very *basic* products like $\sin(mx)\cos(nx)$ show up in many places elsewhere (Fourier series!), and also low powers like $\sin^2(x)$ or $\cos^3(x)$, but when you see a textbook exercise with some crazy-ass combination of trig functions, just regard it as a chance to flex mental muscles rather than think every exercise has to be related to some worthwhile application. If something looks artificial in a purely computational calculus problem, there's a good chance it really is artificial.

I see little point in paying attention to textbook problems directly about  $\cot x$ or $\csc x$ when learning calculus.  In France there isn't a special notation for $\sec x$, or as Henri Cohen once wrote, in France that function "does not exist".

Integrals of high powers of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ can show up in some technical arguments.  For instance, the solution to the Basel problem [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/EulerSeries.shtml) uses integrals of large even powers of $\cos x$ over $[0,\pi/2]$ together with integration by parts.

Comment: séc and coséc **did** "exist" in France, as well as a few other more obscure ones, such as sin v. and cos v. (versine and coversine). I'll have to find my Lespinard & Pernet trigonometry book to check, but I'm sure séc and coséc are mentionned, though not used very much (Henri Cohen, born in 1947, probably had the same book in high school, it was a standard one in the sixties). These functions were probably somewhat useful in the era of tables of logarithms though. The "verse" functions are found in older books (I have found them in Hoüel tables of logarithms from 1893).

Comment: However, the cotangent function is much more useful, and it was taught in Sup' in the late 90s. I suspect it still is. Surprising that you don't see the point.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Let me know what you find in Lespinard & Pernet. I've seen versine and coversine in old math books in English too.  For the record, Henri wrote "The trigonometric functions $\sec x$ and $\csc x$ do not exist in France, so I will not use them" on page ix of his book  *Number Theory Volume II: Analytic and Modern Tools*.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  the comment in my answer about $\cot x$ and $\csc x$ is based on practical experience: many students who take calculus are not familiar with $\cot x$, $\sec x$, and $\csc x$, and in order to learn how to use the main techniques of calculus to solve problems, you don't really need such functions (except we should perhaps allow $\sec x$ "if it exists" since $(\tan x)' =  \sec^2 x$). So rather than suggest to students that they should be familiar with these functions to do well in the course, I let students know they should focus their study time in the course on other things.

Comment: Found it. As I expected, séc and coséc are defined, but not used elsewhere in the book. However, sin, cos, tg *and* cotg are heavily used throughout the book. I agree with your last comment, except for the cotangent, which is good to know.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  thanks.

Comment: The secant function certainly existed in 1879 when Desirée André wrote his papers on the number of alternating permutations. (Given by the coefficients of $\mathop {séc}+\mathop {tang}$.)

Comment: And of course the versine (and more usefully the haversine) played an important part when navigating on the sphere. (They played no part in the education of mathematicians, so I had to learn about them to help a friend gain his Board of Trade 2nd Mate Certificate.)

Answer (score 8):

Although it is true that such exercises are largely contrived, nevertheless complicated trig function *do* occur in real-world applications. One field where they appear a lot is [orbital dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_mechanics). A single planetary orbit is described as an ellipse; that itself comes with relatively harmless formulas like
$$
  r(\vartheta) = \frac{a\cdot(1 - e^2)}{1 - e\cdot\cos \vartheta}
$$
But then you need to perform rotations between different coordinate systems, have objects orbiting another orbiting object, need to compute necessary speed differences to get from one orbit into another (both possibly nested)...
All of this incurs trigonometric terms, and in the end you may well have to deal with a nasty product and/or higher powers.

Another application is [inverse kinematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics) for robotics. Robotic arms often have a whole bunch of joints connected in nontrivial ways. Calculation where the end actuator will be given specified joint angles can be easy enough (sequentially deal with each joint), but if you want to achieve a certain position and want to find out suitable angles then you need to express it all in a single invertible step. That too can give nasty trigonometric terms.

Etc. etc..

Answer (score 5):

The algebra of trigonometric functions is an example of the algebra of rational functions with two generators $\sin, \cos$, their sums, products, powers and finally all quotients of polynomials, with one single additional reduction formula, namely the Euclidean norm on the plane introduced as $\sin^2 + \cos^2 =1$. Without any knowledge of series approximations or integral representation the ancients, the Arabs and the mathematicians up to Euler and Jacoby built the complete algebra circus now filling some 20 pages of any mathematical collection of tables.

The fundamental area of application of the rational field of trignometrics is

1. Fourier transforms as an identity between power series of trigonometrics and Fourier series as harmonic analysis.
2. Representation of all kinds of transformation on Euclidean spheres in any dimensions, eg the inifinite dimensional representation of quantum spin and angular momentum states on spheres in terms of orthogonal power series in trigonometric functions of the angle variables. The meridional standing wave on a water planet between the poles e.g. has the form

$$w_6(t, \theta , \phi) = \sin(6 *7 t) \ \text{LegendreP}(6,\cos(\theta))=\frac{1}{16} \left(231 \ \cos ^6(\theta )- 315 \ \cos ^4(\theta )+105 \ \cos ^2(\theta )-5\right)$$
Harmonic analysis yields
$$=\frac{1}{512} \ (50 + 105 \ \cos(2 \ \theta) + 126 \ \cos(4\  \theta) + 
   231\ \cos(6\ \theta)$$

3. The next step in abstract algebra of fields was termed as the field of elliptic functions by adding a third generator $\text{dn}$ to Jacobis elliptic sine and cosine functions $\text{sn=sin am, cn = cos am}$ with reduction formulas $\text{sn}^2 + \text{cn}^2=1, \text{dn}^2  +k^2\text{sn}^2=1$. This elliptic algebra arose as a disturbation of rotating systems from uniform rotations like the elliptic orbits of planets and the rotation of a pendulum or a spinnig top. Working in these algebras of functions is the last step in geometric algebra before the invention of Spin by Pauli and Dirac, who considered matrix valued algebras of the trigonometrics and elliptics in order to describe the spinning electron.

A standing Pauli-Dirac spin wave of order 6 on a 2-sphere e.g. has the form of a complex vector in the half angle variables typically

$$ w_{\frac{5}{2}}(\theta,\phi) = (a \ e^{i \frac{\phi}{2}} \ \text{P}_6(\theta), b \ e^{i \frac{-\phi}{2}}\ \text{P}_5(\theta))$$
which have the typical property of spin states to change sign by a full rotation of $2\pi$

Comment: Also Tchebychev polynomials like cos(4 acos(x)) which I encountered in the study of spherical aberration in Schmidt optics.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been raised by many mathematicians and one of the best answers in my opinion is the following:

> There is no branch of mathematics, however abstract, which may not some day be  applied to phenomena of the real world.
>
> **(Nikolai Ivanovich Lobachevsky)**

This is about the *branch of mathematics* and your question is about a mathematical expression. In general, any math problem is a very efficient and effective exercise for the brain (and in my opinion for the spirit).

Answer (score 1):

One area where unfamiliar trig functions are needed (at least for those who have to do useful actual calculations by hand rather than just using a computer) is *Spherical Geometry*.

This used to be very important as people needed to be able to *navigate* on the surface of the earth and doing so needed formulae more complicated than the simple ones taught in school that work on on a flat Euclidian plane.

In the days before GPS and calculators, the more complex trig formulae useful for navigation (like the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) needed to calculate great circle distance) were widely taught.

This is a fairly simple example where the need to do calculations relevant to living on a sphere in three dimensions leads to more complex trig formulae arising naturally. The knowledge is no longer familiar to many as spherical geometry is now less essential in a world of GPS and google maps and is rarely a mainstream topic in teaching.

Comment: This was overlooked by previous posters. However, the versine and coversine should also be mentioned. Celestial nav is where I encountered them.  They were an important early success of Babbage’s, leading to a more ambitious failure (that was subsequently constructed and found to work).